# Login POST request using AJAX via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send an AJAX POST request for a login page using javascript via Node.js however I don't really know how to do it. Sorry that I'm really new to this. Here's my code:

In HTML:

```
<form>
  <label for="email"><b>Email Address</b></label><br>
  <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label><br>
  <input type="text" name="password"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" class = "button" value="Login" onclick= "submitlogin()">
</form>
```

In JS:

```
function submitlogin(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(this.readyState ==4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log("success");
} else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 401) {
        console.log("Failed");
}
};
xhttp.open("POST","/login",true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ email: this.email, password: this.password }));
}
```

Route:

```
var user = [{
            EmailAddress: 'anne@gmail.com',
            Password: 'first'
        }]

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
if((req.body.email === user[0].EmailAddress) && user[0].Password === req.body.password){
  res.status(200).send();
} else {
  res.status(401).send();
}
});
```

What should go into xhttp.send()? What am I doing wrongly? Can anyone help me with this? (preferably just javascript not jQuery) Thank you!

Comment: You are confusing two different ways of doing http requests. Why don't you simply do it with your angular spa. It is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical issue about how to deal with the info passed to server using a way that you didn't expected.

There's a lot of things to improve in your code, but i won't focus on this right now. So, first of all, if you pay attention to what happens in your browser right after the submit button is clicked, on the URL you can see the typed inputs in querystring format. And it isn't referencing the /login route descripted.

Something like:

`http://localhost:3000/?email=marcelobraga%40hotmail.com&password=agoodpassword`

It happened because the Form element, by default, uses the parameters to communicate with your server. Not the object "Body" that you're expecting to receive through the HTTP Request object.

If you really want to access the login data passed as URL parameters, you will need just to fix your code in your front and backend to pass correctly object and prepare your server to read it on the right place.

I strongly advise you not to use the form html element this way. Either use the XMLHttpRequest. I suggest to use the Axios to do deal with the HTTP requests and send Body informations to avoid explicit such a sensitive information like logins could be. Other reason to use Axios is for easy syntax and clean code.

**See how i made it with axios:**

In HTML (I will insert all the HTML to you see the importation the Axios Lib tag):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script> <!-- importing axios to this document -->
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="email"><b>Email Address</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
    <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" onclick="submitlogin()">
</body>
</html>
```

In JS file:

```
        const emailInput = document.getElementById("email").value //getting the value from input typed
        const passwordInput = document.getElementById("password").value //getting the value from input typed

        axios.post('/login', 
        {
            email: emailInput,
            password: passwordInput
        }
    )};
```

In expressjs:

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); //console to verify the body data received on this endpoint request

    const user = [{
        EmailAddress: 'anne@gmail.com',
        Password: 'first'
    }];

    if((req.body.email === user[0].EmailAddress) && user[0].Password === req.body.password){
        res.status(200).send("Success");
        console.log("Success");
      } else {
        res.status(401).send("Wrong email or password");
        console.log("Wrong email or password");
      }
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

**Conclusion**

The way that you was doing this made the data unreachable on the backend. The backend was expecting to receive the information to proceed with the verifications on the Body data of the Request. And you was passing it as a query parameter.

You can pass information using params or query params to the backend, but the login information must be more protected. Sending it in your body avoid people to find this data lookin in your history, for example. It's not the most secure way, because someone can catch this data on the middle. But, anyway, is something you should know.

I hope i could help you.